# findViewById(int) returns null on one specific button in Android 3.1 other versions its fine

Tags: java, android, xml, findviewbyid

It's my first question but I'm trying to ask correctly.

As the title says only on one button and only in android 3.1 findViewById(int) returns null. Testing on Android 2.2 it works and all other buttons are found in both Android versions. It finds buttons before this specific line and afterwards.

```java
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Button buttonInfo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonInfo);//fine
buttonInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
...
Button buttonCallOpScreen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCallOpScreen);//always returns null in android 3.1
...
Button buttonTakePicture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonTakePictureMain);//fine
buttonTakePicture.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

`main.xml`:

(I do know that I should not use `px`, but it shall work on my device only, so that's fine for this case.)

```
<Button 
android:id="@+id/buttonInfo" 
android:text=""
android:layout_width="332px"
android:layout_height="100px"
android:background="@drawable/btn_team" />
...
<Button
android:id="@+id/buttonCallOpScreen"
android:text=""
android:layout_width="332px"
android:layout_height="100px"
android:background="@drawable/btn_operator" />
...
<Button 
android:id="@+id/buttonTakePictureMain" 
android:text=""
android:layout_width="80px" 
android:layout_height="80px"
android:background="@drawable/btn_take_picture"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|left" />
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks so far.

---

**Answer:**

It turned out to be a more than ugly. As there are several persons working on this project one of seemed to have changed the name in the layout-normal/main.xml. While Android-Versions before 3.1 seem to load layout/main.xml the newer ones use layout-normal/main.xml. And as it is more than understandable if the id of that button is a different findViewById(int) has to return null.

Sorry for bothering you with that and thanks for the comments!

As I do have less than 100 reputation, I can't answer my own question to close it, if anyone could post this answer I would accept it, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: select the project and clean and rebuild the project from project menu bar

Comment: thanks for that quick answer, already tried - without success

Comment: change id of button and then see results

Comment: uninstalling the app from phone and restarting eclipse has helped me sometimes.

Comment: You don't have a different layout for that API version, do you?

Comment: i did uninstalling... without success, but i do not have different layouts for different versions - i do i realize that?

Comment: it's work fine in 3.1 I have test your code, I think your eclipse problem for generating the R.java file

Comment: checked the R.java there is one entry: public static final int buttonCallOpScreen=0x7f060032;

Comment: also tried modifying the id, but it didn't work as well

Comment: MArtin, to close the question, you need to post the solution as an answer and accep it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer was discovered by the person who asked the question.  The details are:

> As there are several persons working on this project one of seemed to
>   have changed the name in the layout-normal/main.xml. While
>   Android-Versions before 3.1 seem to load layout/main.xml the newer
>   ones use layout-normal/main.xml. And as it is more than understandle
>   if the id of that button is a different findViewById(int) has to
>   return null.